# Check if an int[] array is in range using if statements in Java

Tags: java, arrays, integer, operator-keyword

My code looks like this:

```
public Goals​(int[] points){
    this.points = points;
}
```

then I'll have to check if the array is within the range:

```
public int getpoints() {
    if (points <= 0 && >= 10) {
             //do something
    }
}
```

but it doesn't allow me to use operators with arrays.

How should I do this?

Comment: What does that mean? Do you want to check if any element in the array is within this range? All of them? The sum of the array? Something else?

Comment: please give more details to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you trying to check if points are within the range of 0 and 10, you could use something like

```
public class InRange {

public static void main(String[] args){
    checkRange();
}

private static void checkRange() {
    int[] points = new int[3];
    points[0] = -1;
    points[1] = 6;
    points[2] = 11;
    
    for(int i = 0; i<points.length; i++){
        if(points[i] >= 0 && points[i]<=10){
            System.out.println(points[i] + " Point between 0 and 10");
        }else{
            System.out.println(points[i] + " Point not Between 0 and 10");
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right, it would do the trick:

```
private static boolean isWithinRange(int[] points, int minRange, int maxRange) {
  boolean outOfRange = Arrays.stream(points).anyMatch( p -> p < minRange || p > maxRange );
  return ! outOfRange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know your question, but if you looking for a way to check if all of element in points array is in range, check this

```
boolean isInRange = Arrays.stream(points).allMatch(point -> [Your condition for each element]);
```